# Is there a way to hide radio buttons using CSS?

Tags: css, radio-button, qualtrics

I have a survey on Qualtrics and I would like to find a way of hiding the radio buttons using CSS; is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: `input[type="radio"] { display: none; }`?

Comment: The above selector is correct but will hide radio buttons on all the documents on your site sharing the same stylesheet so make sure you use some wrapper class name or id in your selector to target specific ones, also that will remove the physical space from the document so using something like `visibility: hidden;` can be handy for you

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to also hide the associated text?

Comment: the label you mean ?

Comment: input[type="rafio"] > label {display: none;}

Comment: hmm that didn't seem to work

Would the entire code look like this?




    input[type=radio]{
    visibility: hidden;  
}

input[type=checkbox] > label {display: none;}

Comment: input[type="radio"]:first-child {display: none;}  you can also try this

Comment: id the text in not inside a  p or other html tag this will not work util you remove it manually or with JavaScript

Comment: Can you explain that last bit some more?

Comment: if you want a usefull answer you should let us know about your html structure ... if label and input are display:none; then they are useless, no way to check/uncheck them. remove them from html... just writing :)

Answer (score 3):

if you want all radiobuttons hidden then you can use

```
input [type="radio"] { display:none; }
```

if you want only some radiobuttons hidden then you must give a css class for them for example "hiddenRadioButton" and this css class is

```
.hiddenRadioButton{ display:none; }
```

Edit: `[input type="radio"] {display:none}` should be `input [type="radio"] { display:none; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide a certain radio button, then use this:

HTML:

```
<!-- Example with two radio buttons -->
<input type="radio" id="first-button" name="button"> <input type="radio" id="second-button" name="button">
```

CSS:

```
#first-button {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to hide all the radio buttons then User Vecihi Baltacl's answer will not work, you need to use this CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several way of hiding stuff it depending of what you want achieve:

- hide because you don't need it or you will show it from js when some condition will be met. For this you should use `display: none;`. That elements are not in the DOM.
- hide because you will do some crazy hack for eg. because you are lazy and you don want to modify POST or deal with date on backend. Then you should use `visibility: hidden;` that element are in the DOM.
- -hide because you want to style it differently (and stupid :D browsers don't allow you to do that). This days is not recommended
  because be have so many devices which behave in many different ways
  that will cause some problem for eg. on mobile (of course not
  always). For that you should use `opacity: 0;`. They render on page in place where they should be but are just not visible.

My personal favourite for this:

```
.container{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.hidden-stuff{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 30rem;  
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

There is nice way of styling radio buttons by css ninja http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css